# C++ Des encryption with 16 bytes key

Tags: c++, des

I'm trying to encrypt in DES a text with dynamic length with a 16 bytes key, but there is a problem with the block size of the key and text, i'm using openssl library for DES encryption. How can I use keys with 16 bytes of length.

Here my example:

```
char * Encrypt( char Key, char *Msg, int size) { 
      static char*    Res;
      DES_cblock      Key2;
      DES_key_schedule schedule;

      Res = ( char * ) malloc( size );

      memcpy(Key2, Key, 8);
      DES_set_odd_parity( &Key2 );
      DES_set_key_checked( &Key2, &schedule );

      unsigned char buf[9];    
      buf[8] = 0;

      DES_ecb_encrypt(( DES_cblock  ) &Msg, ( DES_cblock  ) &buf, &schedule, DES_ENCRYPT );    
      memcpy(Res, buf, sizeof(buf));    
      return (Res);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
      char key[] = "password";
      char clear[] = "This is a secret message";
      char *encrypted;

      encrypted = (char *) malloc(sizeof(clear));

      printf("Clear text\t : %s \n",clear); 

      memcpy(encrypted, Encrypt(key, clear, sizeof(clear)), sizeof(clear));

      printf("Encrypted text\t : %s \n",encrypted);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be careful, you have a memory leak in the code you show. Where do you free the memory you allocate in the `Encrypt` function?

Comment: Does AES accept 16-byte key?

Comment: AES allows 128, 192 and 256 bit keys.

Comment: AES = "Advanced Encryption Standard", DES = "Deprecated Encryption Standard"™.

Comment: Since this is C++ code, you should not be using raw pointers nor doing manual memory management. To safely manage memory buffers, use `std::vector<char>` or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. DES has a 8-byte 56-bit key (the LSB is not used as part of the key, it is for parity) so you can't use a 16-byte key (parity is generally ignored).
2. Don't use DES, it is not secure and has been replaced with AES.
3. Don't use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

AES allows 128, 192 and 256 bit keys.

Comment: I agree - DES shouldn't be used anymore, it can be broken in hours by a motivated attacker.